# Ease class to classic tween in Animate CC?

Tags: createjs

Is it possible with small script just to inject missing ease class on existed non-coded classic tween in Animate CC? Something like: this.movieclip.tween = Ease.elasticOut;

Comment: Can you include an example of the code from the existing 'non-coded' classic tween?

Comment: I dont have any code.